# Local Stack v. Dev Server

Tags: drupal, development-environment

I am currently working on a Drupal project. Being a developer, I have often heard disagreements on whether it is better to develop on a local stack or on a shared development server. To anyone here with Drupal experience, do you have any insight or advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

#### This is nothing Drupal-specific.

Everybody should work on their local machine. In a local development environment. There are thousands of options to choose from to make your own computer run a website locally. Start with [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info) maybe.

Use Git (and the [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)) to commit your changes to a repo where your co-workers can pull them from into their local environment.

Use deployment routines or webhooks to have your changes pulled onto the live server on every release automatically.

---

#### When developing things always move in two directions:

- Database copies move down (from live to dev to local).
- Code changes move up (from local to dev to live).

---

What should be good when multiple persons work on one and the same code instance at once? Nothing. Imagine all the conflicts that can arise from two persons working on one file at the same time. Insane!